# Ubuntu 11.10 on Asus K53TA Laptop no screen error?

Tags: 11.10, laptop, screen, asus, ati

I have an Asus K53 laptop with a AMD A6 APU and I cant seem to get the screen to work for GUI mode. I can Install it with the alternate CD but I can only see a blinking cursor then no screen detected error pops up for about a second. its got a Radeon HD 6720G2. I have also tried running "startx" in terminal mode but the same error was outputted.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Update, the ubuntu is trying to send the video signal via HDMI, try plugging it in to an external monitor and then once installed update the Radeon drivers and divert the signal back the the laptop screen, this has worked for many people.